# Workaround for setBackgroundDrawable on android?

Tags: android

The `setBackgroundDrawable()` method of the `View` class in is now deprecated in android SDK API level 16.

The new method is `setBackground()` but of course it's only available in API 16.

How can I workaround it if I want my application to be compatible with previous API levels ? (at least API 14)

The goal is to eliminate any warnings and an @SupressWarnings is not a solution for me.

Comment: have You tried '@TargetApi' annotation? (Seems Lint itself suggests that way)

Comment: @SuppressWarnings *is* the solution.  If you're targetting API 14, and you don't need any functionality of the new API, then calling the older API and suppressing the warning is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The usual way is this one:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
  setBackground(...);
else
  setBackgroundDrawable(...);
```

On the other hand you could use reflections:

```
try {
  Method setBackground = View.class.getMethod("setBackground", Drawable.class);
  setBackground.invoke(myView, myDrawable);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  setBackgroundDrawable(myDrawable);
}
```

IMO a warning is better than having to catch an exception and an unnecessary reflection.

Comment: and therefore can use @SupressWarning in the else clause ?

Comment: There's no reason to add two code paths.  Just call the deprecated method unless your target is 16+ or you actually need functionality in the new API.

Comment: this required minsdk to be 16.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
viewobj.setBackgroundResource(drawble_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting bitmap to ImageView.

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSlice4);
imageSlice4.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), slicedImagesArrayList.get(3)));